# Cannot read property 'udp' of undefined in ionic

Tags: cordova, sockets, ionic-framework, udp

I installed the plugin cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp

According to the official instance create socket

```
chrome.sockets.udp.create({}, function(socketInfo) {
   // The socket is created, now we can send some data
   var socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
   chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, arrayBuffer,
     '127.0.0.1', 1337, function(sendInfo) {
     console.log("sent " + sendInfo.bytesSent);
 });
});
```

But there is a Error Cannot read property 'udp' of undefined

What reason is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your code around [`$ionicPlatform.ready`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/) like this :

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    chrome.socket.udp.create({}, function(socketInfo) {
      var socketId = socketInfo.socketId;
      chrome.sockets.udp.send(socketId, arrayBuffer,
        '127.0.0.1', 1337,
        function(sendInfo) {
          console.log("sent " + sendInfo.bytesSent);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

**Update:** If you see any cordova plugin's `plugin.xml` file's [`<clobber>`](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-socket/blob/master/plugin.xml#L23) node, it has the namespace the plugin is available at. If thats the issue.

Comment: Thanks and answer ,I refer to your methods to do it ,But it's still the same error , If I still need to introduce chrome service?

Comment: or it might be `chrome.socket`. atleast try seeing what `chrome.socket` holds ...

Comment: I tried a variety of writing, but still an error , udp plugins the namespace is this : '<js-module src="sockets.udp.js" name="sockets.udp"> <clobbers target="chrome.sockets.udp" />  </js-module>'